# Custom Button URL help

Tags: button, url

We  have a button on the opportunity object that is a part of the Octive managed package and is submitting the proposal for an approval when clicked. We would like to customize it so that when the opportunity is at stage `'Closed or Lost'` or `'Closed or Won'` and user clicks the button they get an error message.

The button URL is as following:

```
/apex/tinderbox__create_document?sObjectType=Opportunity&recordId={!Opportunity.Id}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about this package, generically speaking, you can change it to a JavaScript button:

```
var url = '/apex/tinderbox__create_document?sObjectType=Opportunity&recordId={!Opportunity.Id}';
if({!ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName,'Closed or Lost') || ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName,'Closed or Won')}) {
    alert('You cannot do this.');
} else {
    if(sforce && sforce.one) {
        sforce.one.navigateToUrl(url);
    } else if(sforce && sforce.console) {
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, url);
    } else {
        window.top.location = url;
    }
}
```

You'll need to change the Behavior to "Onclick JavaScript."

Comment: Worked like a charm! @sfdcfox